Dynamic Colored Line Chart in Workshop module using code repository
I'm rendering the line chart using code repository function but not getting color for that line chart.
I'm using 2D chart so based on the trend I want dynamic colored chart like if it's going up then green, if going down then red and if stable then black.
so I'm not able to produce code to color the line chart using code repository. If anyone have any idea then please drop here!
